# How to create instance/tag that will be replace by username for composed email in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email

I am trying to build email sender for contact list with a personal appeal to recipients.
My email model has 2 attributes: title and body. 
Contact model has username and email.
How can I mark some instance/tag inside my email.body that will be replace by contact.username after email.create

email.body can be like:
"Hi dear #username..." 
and I need to send a text like 
"Hi dear John Doe..."

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write your emails in the file format `emailname.html.erb` so you can do something like:

```
Dear <%= @contact.username %>,
```

You will just need to define the variable @user in your mailer method, like this:

```
def new_message(contact)
    @contact = contact
    mail(to: contact.email, subject: "Hello")
end
```